# Powershell NULL Error

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

For some reason when I click Ok on my form to send an e-mail, it says my Subject is null or empty.

But it doesn't complain about e-mail. Yet the code for both is almost exactly the same.

Am I missing something really simple here? It's been a long day.

```powershell
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 
$Icon = New-Object system.drawing.icon ("C:test.ico")
$objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
$objForm.Text = "EXAMPLE"
$objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,350) 
$objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"
$objForm.Icon = $Icon
$objForm.KeyPreview = $True
$objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
    {$objForm.Close()}})

[string] $USER = $objEmailTextBox.Text
[string] $SUBJECT = $objSubjectTextBox.Text
[string] $BODY = $objBodyTextBox.Text
$OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,270)
$OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(100,23)
$OKButton.Text = "Submit Ticket"
$objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    SEND-EMAIL($USER, $SUBJECT, $BODY)
})

$CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(175,270)
$CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
$CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
$CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
$objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

$objEmailLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objEmailLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
$objEmailLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(37,20) 
$objEmailLabel.Text = "Email:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objEmailLabel) 

$objEmailTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objEmailTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,17) 
$objEmailTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objEmailTextBox) 

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(45,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Subject:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objSubjectTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objSubjectTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,39) 
$objSubjectTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,20) 
$objForm.Controls.Add($objSubjectTextBox) 

$objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,63) 
$objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(45,20) 
$objLabel.Text = "Body:"
$objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

$objBodyTextBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$objBodyTextBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(55,60) 
$objBodyTextBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(200,150) 
$objBodyTextBox.MultiLine = $True
$objForm.Controls.Add($objBodyTextBox)


Function SEND-EMAIL([String] $USER, [String] $SUBJ, [String]$BODYTEXT)
{
    send-mailmessage -to "bla@blah.com" -from $USER -subject $SUBJ -SmtpServer mail.blah.com -body $BODYTEXT -BodyAsHtml
}


$objForm.Topmost = $True

$objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
[void] $objForm.ShowDialog()

$x


OUTPUT: ERROR: Send-MailMessage : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Subject'. The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try th
ERROR: e command again.
test.ps1 (69): ERROR: At Line: 69 char: 68
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning $USER/SUBJECT/BODY while the form is being created.  The user hasn't had a chance to enter anything yet.  Try getting the values when the OK button click handler executes:

```
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    $user = $objEmailTextBox.Text
    $subject = $objSubjectTextBox.Text
    $body = $objBodyTextBox.Text
    Send-Email $user $subject $body
})
```

Also remember that you call PowerShell functions (commands) like any other command.  Use space separated args.  And you don't need the parens unless you have an expression that needs evaluating.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell functions are called using *function1 param1 param2* rather than *function(param1,param2)* syntax, so change:

```powershell
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    SEND-EMAIL($USER, $SUBJECT, $BODY)
...
```

to:

```powershell
$OKButton.Add_Click({
    SEND-EMAIL $USER $SUBJECT $BODY
...
```

Only .Net functions called from Powershell use  the *function(param1,param2)* notation.